# Self certify that the package is lightning ready

Tags: lightning, package, security-review, 2gp, lightning-ready

How do I certify that my package is Lightning ready? Is that something that we have to raise the case with the community?

In the checklist, it shows that I have to "Self-certify listing as Lightning Ready via [these instructions](https://sfdc.co/LightningReady) but this doesn't seem to work. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to test if it behaves correctly in the Lightning Experience.

Also, it is suggested to use LWC for building UI

When you check this checkbox, it will have the Supported Features "Lightning Ready" in the list like is depicted on screenshot

[image]

Comment: So we don't need to go to salesforce or raise case to get certified?

Comment: well, I can't open the document you shared. However, when I submitted my app built on LWC, I just checked this checkbox, since it has only Lightning Experience tab and actually doesn't have Salesforce Classic app, so it is definitely Lightning Ready

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2tgy.png